# A proof in $\mathbb{R}^2$ regarding the Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $u,v$ be a pair of smooth, real valued functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $(x,y)$ be a point on $\mathbb{R^2}$. Show that the mapping $(x,y)\to(u,v)$ is conformal at the points where the Jacobian matrix does not vanish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question - here it is:

The Cauchy Riemann equations are 
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$
The Jacobian matrix is
$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix}$$
Is of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ -b & a\end{pmatrix}$$
If $r^2:=a^2+b^2$, and $r^2\neq0$, then it is possible to write $a=r\sin\theta,b=r\cos\theta$ for some angle $\theta$, and therefore, the Jacobian represents a rotation by $\theta$ with an dilation by the factor of $r$, which is a conformal transformation from $(x,y)\to(u,v)$.